# Access to the elements of a resource dictionary of c# code by name

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, resourcedictionary

How I can code in c# to get access to the Image **my_image_name** in the resource?
And as I gave resource dictionary name **mydic_name**. Can I refer to the dictionary by name?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="mydic_name">
                    <Image x:Name="my_image_name" x:Key="my_image_key" Source="Properties/images/device1.png"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `ResourceDictionary` is loaded yo can do something like this:

```
 var image = (Image)Application.Current.Resources.FindName("my_image_name");
```

Comment: While this is a valid answer to the question, I must mention that the very fact of wanting to access these kind of things in code is a signal of a poor application design. WPF UI elements should not be manipulated in code, at least not in the "traditional" way.

Comment: @HighCore, I totally aggree, you can take the programmer off WinForms, but you can't take Winforms off the programmer :)

Comment: sadly true =( - that's why we should immediately bury winforms under the deep sea, where nobody ever finds it again.

Comment: Even if we sank it in the deepest ocean it would still flicker when we move the mouse, LOL

Comment: There are actually times where this is a very reasonable solution. I am sadly facing such an occasion and it certainly does not always imply a poor application design

Comment: What happened has happened  and it couldn't happen  in another way.